# New Relic Agent iOS uncaught exception (std::runtime_error)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, newrelic

I'm experiencing an issue starting the NewRelicAgent for iOS. I can guarantee that till yesterday the service worked. Today when the app starts and invoke:

```
[NewRelicAgent startWithApplicationToken:NEWRELICAGENT_SERIVCE_AUTH_KEY];
```

the app crashes and raises this exception:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   std::runtime_error: unrecognized event type in stream.

[Screenshot where Xcode raises the sigabart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQS2d.png)

In general, since i can't step inside the method with the debugger because the nature of the framework, how can i understand or take the right direction to catch the problem in situations like this?

Comment: r u changed Xcode version?

Comment: No, i'm using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue during new relic upgrade. By mistake i disabled the new relic run script in build phases which caused this error. Adding the new relic run script in build phases fixed the issue for me.